# Trying to save function's result on php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

I have a function like this. The function to make a random code for voucher in my program :

```
<?php
function rcode() {
  //rancangan kode
  $fak = mysql_query("select * from master where master.npm = '$_SESSION[username]'"); // dapat dari inputan
  while ($fakk = mysql_fetch_array($fak)) {
      $_SESSION['id_fak'] = $fakk['id_fak'];
  };
  $fakultas = "0" . $_SESSION['id_fak'];
  $jur = mysql_query("select id from master where master.npm = '$_SESSION[username]'"); // dapat dari inputan
  while ($jurr = mysql_fetch_array($jur)) {
      $_SESSION['id'] = $jurr['id'];
  };
  $jurusan = $_SESSION['id'];

  $result = mysql_query("
      SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'konfirmasi'
  ");
  $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $next_increment = $data['Auto_increment'];
  //$next_increment = 99999;

  if ($next_increment < 10) {
      $voucher = $fakultas . "00" . $jurusan . "0" . "0" . $next_increment;
      echo $voucher;
  } else if ($next_increment < 100 and $next_increment >= 10) {
      $voucher = $fakultas . "00" . $jurusan . "0" . $next_increment;
      echo $voucher;
  } else if ($next_increment < 1000 and $next_increment >= 100) {
      $voucher = $fakultas . "00" . $jurusan . $next_increment;
      echo $voucher;
  } else if ($next_increment < 10000 and $next_increment >= 1000) {
      $depan = substr($next_increment, 0, 1);
      $sisa = substr($next_increment, 1, 3);
      $voucher = $fakultas . "0" . $depan . $jurusan . $sisa;
      echo $voucher;
  } else if ($next_increment >= 10000) {
      $puluhribuan = substr($next_increment, 0, 1);
      $ribuan = substr($next_increment, 1, 1);
      $sisa = substr($next_increment, 2, 3);

      $voucher = $fakultas . $puluhribuan . $ribuan . $jurusan . $sisa;
      echo $voucher;
  }
  //echo rand();
}

?>
```

so, I try to insert on my sql, but it's should work.
here is the code :

```
<?php
rcode();
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['konfirmasi'])) {
    $voucherr = rcode();
    mysql_query("insert into konfirmasi(voucher) values('$voucherr')");
} else {
    ?>
    <form action="tampilbarcode.php" action="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="konfirmasi" value="CETAK PDF">
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```

**Please Help me, this is for my thesis program.**

Comment: You will need to better rephrase your problem, and tell us what isn't working? Or if it's not working as intended, what was the issue.

Comment: I wanna insert the result from $voucher on rcode() function in my sql but I tryng to insert it but still did'n work. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do `return $voucher` instead of `echo $voucher` at the end of `rcode()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple....

```
echo $voucher;
```

will not work as the function must return something. So in order to get   something in return you have to use return $voucher; which you will get in $voucher in

```
$voucherr = rcode();
```

and then you can send that value to your insert query.